# Better way to read columns from excel file as variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, variables, xlrd

I have an .xlsx file with 5 columns(X,Y,Z,Row_Cog,Col_Cog) and will be in the same order each time. I would like to have each column as a variable in python. I am implementing the below method but would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

Also I am writing the range manually(in the for loop) while I would like to have a robust way to know the length of each column in excel(no of rows) and assign it.

```
#READ THE TEST DATA from Excel file
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\Desktop\SawToothCalib\TestData.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

X_Test=[]
Y_Test=[]

Row_Test=[]
Col_Test=[]

for i in range(1, 29):

        x_val= worksheet.cell_value(i,0)
        X_Test.append(x_val)

        y_val= worksheet.cell_value(i,2)
        Y_Test.append(y_val)

        row_val= worksheet.cell_value(i,3)
        Row_Test.append(row_val)
         
        col_val= worksheet.cell_value(i,4)
        Col_Test.append(col_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need this package? You can easily do this kind of operation with pandas.

You can read your file as a DataFrame with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(path + 'file.xlsx', sheet_name=the_sheet_you_want)
```

and access the list of columns with `df.columns`. You can acces each column with `df['column name']`. If there are empty entries, they are stored as NaN. You can know how many you have with `df['column_name'].isnull()`.
If you are uncomfortable with DataFrames, you can then convert the columns to lists or arrays, like

```
df['my_col'].tolist()
```

or

```
df['my_col'].to_numpy()
```